# Workbook.open issues

Tags: excel, vba

Hello I am trying to open a file with reference to a cell G13, first few times it work but after wards i am unable to have the code work anymore.

Please help

```
Sub ConvertTextToNumbers()
Dim wBook As Workbook
Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long
Dim Rangetemp As Range
Dim Workbook1 As Range

Set Workbook1 = Range("G13")
'Enter here the path of your workbook
Set wBook = Workbooks.Open("Workbook1")
LastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Range("A1"), SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
LastCol = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Range("A1"), SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column

For c = 1 To LastCol
Set Rangetemp = Cells(c).EntireColumn
Rangetemp.TextToColumns DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
    :=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: `Set wBook = Workbooks.Open("Workbook1")` you are trying to open a workbook called "Workbook1", not the workbook referenced in the Workbook1 variable.

Comment: Note that *"Does not work"* is completely useless as error description. Which error do you get and in which line. Please read [ask] to improve your question. The line should be `Set wBook = Workbooks.Open(Workbook1)` if you wish to use the value of the variable `Workbook1`.